# !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 624). IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed when calling .verifyPhoneNumber() method

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error when I call `verifyPhoneNumber()` method..there is nothing wrong with my phone auth codes since it's working perfectly fine before I changed my bundleId and redownloaded the `google-service.json` file.
my project got messed up since I changed my bundle id and changed my google-service.json I don't know what to do since I'm new to coding and don't have any idea what this stack trace is talking about.

in ios, the app is being killed and leaving no stack trace at all. in android, I'm getting this stack trace.

what I've tried:
flutter clean,
flutter pub get,
flutter pub cache repair
deleted the build folder, .gradle folder, podfile.lock and pods folder , then run flutter run -v to recreate the folders but it didn't fix the problem.

any help would be greatly appreciated. i can show more details if needed.

```html
E/JavaBinder(12658): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 624)
W/GmsClient(12658): IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
W/GmsClient(12658): android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffe
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:8)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:14)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabt.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/JavaBinder(12658): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 624)
W/GmsClient(12658): IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
W/GmsClient(12658): android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffe
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:8)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:14)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabt.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/JavaBinder(12658): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 624)
W/GmsClient(12658): IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
W/GmsClient(12658): android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffe
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/GmsClient(12658):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
```

Comment: I have similar error, but its working ok with emulator and read devices including iOS

Comment: @Kobi After i messed up my project because of this problem, I figured out that in andoid, this has something to do with an internet connection or Bluetooth. So to fix it, just turn off and on your Bluetooth and internet connection. For the Ios, I deleted all the files inside the ios directory except the runner folder then ran `flutter create .` then run `flutterfire configure` to reconfigure firebase and it fixed my problem. The heartbreaking part is it took me 4 days to realize how simple the fix is.

Answer (score 2):

Try following.

1. Flutter clean.
2. File < Invalidate cache and restart the project.
3. close the connection with the virtual device or if using the emulator, close and restart it.
4. run the project.

it worked for me.

Comment: as i said in my post, I did everything you said but didn't work. Then only to find out that is an emulator problem. I deleted the emulator and create a new one and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
One of the initialization function in initState() was too long, with a lot of printing to log and multiple updating a status variable.
I reduce the printing and the status updating and.... everything is working